# How to dump data from MSSQL to XML with SQL Agent?

Tags: sql-server, xml, dump, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

**I need to export data with SQL procedure from MSSQL (2012) to XML and run the script periodically with SQL Server Agent.**

I would like to do it directly from SQL Server, because now I am doing it with console application which is generating XML structure from raw data from SQL and it takes over 10 hours! An output XML now has 300M.

Does somebody now how to do it? I already have stored procedure generating XML output.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks much.

The procedure was executed successfully. I only had to set up rights for a destination folder for user "SQLSERVERAGENT", because Agent finishes successfully but wrote nothing.

But I have a small problem with final XML. At the beginning and at the end of XML file are included some information from Agent.

**Do somebody know how to remove Header and Footer?**

Header:

```
Job 'Xml Dump' : Step 1, 'Xml Dump Procedure' : Began Executing 2013-07-23 12:24:52

XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Footer:

```
(146270 rows(s) affected)
```

---

**Stored procedure contains this**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetXmlDumpCompleteData
(@Xml XML)
as
    SET @Xml = (SELECT * FROM [MyTable]

        FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('data'))
    SELECT @Xml
```

**Command in job agent**:

```
DECLARE @Xml XML

EXEC    [dbo].[GetXmlDumpCompleteData]
        @Xml = @Xml OUTPUT

SELECT  @Xml as N'@Xml'

GO
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer, if i knew what is your procedure

Comment: My stored procedure returns XML in OUTPUT. But Job Agent returns XML with header and footer.